# Amazon cognito authentication for Kibana in ElasticSearch hosted in VPC - Link does not load for kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cognito

I have an ES domain and I want to access Kibana locally from within the same browser. Reading the documentation, it said that i could use Amazon Cognito to do the same with authentication for the users. I set the whole thing up as per the following AWS documentation [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html)

The problem is, whenever i try to access kibana from the browser using the link which looks like this :

```
https://vpc-something1-something2.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/
```

the request times out. I'll post my access policy for the ES cluster here :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_ID:role/Cognito_Something_Auth_Role"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:Account_ID:domain/domain_name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I followed the procedure in the above link exactly and created a user group, identity group etc. But the link does not seem to load. Any help would be much appreciated.
PS : I'm new to AWS.
All this is assuming that i can directly access Kibana through my browser if i have cognito set up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ES cluster is created in a VPC, then you need networking access to it. I would recommend creating a cluster with 'Public access' instead, which is still subject to your access policy.

If you want a VPC cluster, and you want to access it (either ES directly, or Kibana) from outside that VPC, then you will need to VPN into the VPC, or do some routing that enables it to be exposed. The latter might be a bit tricky when the instances running your cluster aren't directly available to you, but you should be able to do it with some combination of Internet gateways, NAT gateways, security groups, routing tables, etc.

This might help: [Connecting to a VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-vpc/)

Comment: Thank you :) The VPC connection was the problem. Had to create a new one with public access.